# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'json' argument must be an instance of: [class java.lang.String, class [B

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, resttemplate, sap-commerce-cloud

I am making a third party request in Hybris1811 framework using Spring Rest Template . But after getting response I am  Getting below error:

```
Could not properly initialize user sessionorg.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: 
Request processing failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'json' argument must be an instance of: [class java.lang.String, class [B, class java.io.File, class java.net.URL, class java.io.InputStream, class java.io.Reader] , but gotten: class org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.
```

when I try to implement the below code:

<int:gateway id="testRequestGateway"
service-interface="com.test.testb2bintegrations.payment.gateway.testRequestGateway"
default-request-channel="MytestReqRequestChannel"
default-reply-channel="MytestReqResponseChannel"/>

```
<int:channel id="MytestReqRequestChannel"/>

<int:header-enricher input-channel="MytestReqRequestChannel" output-channel="MytestReqEnrichedRequestChannel">
    <int:header name="x-api-key" value="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('myKey')}"/>
    <int:header name="Content-Type" value="application/json;charset=UTF-8" />
</int:header-enricher>


<int:object-to-json-transformer input-channel="MytestReqEnrichedRequestChannel"
                                output-channel="MytestReqJSONRequestChannel"/>

<int-http:outbound-gateway
        url="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('myURL')}"
        http-method="POST"
        header-mapper="testPaymentHeaderMapper"
        rest-template="testSubmitPaymentRestTemplate"
        request-channel="MytestReqJSONRequestChannel"
        reply-channel="MytestReqJSONResponseChannel"
        charset="UTF-8"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<int:json-to-object-transformer input-channel="MytestReqJSONResponseChannel"
                                output-channel="MytestReqResponseChannel"
                                type="com.test.testb2bintegrations.models.payment.request.testSubmitPaymentResponseVO"/>

<int:channel id="MytestReqResponseChannel"/>
```

Interceptor Code :

```
public class TestRequestLoggingInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor
{

@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException
{
    ClientHttpResponse response;
    try
    {
        request.getHeaders().setAcceptCharset(Collections.singletonList(Charsets.UTF_8));
        long startTimeinMillis = new Date().getTime();
        response = execution.execute(request, body);
        logResponse(response);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LOGGER.error("Error when trying to fetch the information : " + e.getMessage());
        throw new IOException("Connection was unsuccessful!", e);
    }
    return response;
}

private void logResponse(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException
{
       String lineSeparator = System.lineSeparator();
        String responseBody = StreamUtils.copyToString(response.getBody(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder responseLog = new StringBuilder();
        responseLog.append("=======================Response Begin==========================").append(lineSeparator);
        responseLog.append("Status code  : {" + response.getStatusCode() + "}").append(lineSeparator);
        responseLog.append("Status text  : {" + response.getStatusText() + "}").append(lineSeparator);
        responseLog.append("Headers      : {" + response.getHeaders() + "}").append(lineSeparator);
        responseLog.append("Response body: {" + responseBody + "}").append(lineSeparator);
        responseLog.append("======================Response End==============================").append(lineSeparator);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from the `<int:json-to-object-transformer>` when it tries to convert a reply from the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` into your `testSubmitPaymentResponseVO` object.

But it turns out that reply is not a plain string as you would expect using `expected-response-type="java.lang.String"`, but the whole `ResponseEntity`.

We have there a logic like this:

```
    if (httpResponse.hasBody()) {
        Object responseBody = httpResponse.getBody();
        replyBuilder = (responseBody instanceof Message<?>)
                ? messageBuilderFactory.fromMessage((Message<?>) responseBody)
                : messageBuilderFactory.withPayload(responseBody); // NOSONAR - hasBody()

    }
    else {
        replyBuilder = messageBuilderFactory.withPayload(httpResponse);
    }
```

So, looks like that `url="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('myURL')}"` REST service returns nothing back to you as an HTTP response.

Nothing what we can help with: we don't control that service so you should consult with them what is wrong in the request you send to them.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, strange thing is when I don't log ClientHttpResponse response.getBody() in overriden intercept() method from ClientHttpRequestInterceptor. It works absolutely fine. I get response . I am not sure why.

Comment: Show your interceptor code, please. Probably you need to use an `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` for that `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` if you can't get rid of your interceptor...

Comment: Please check edited question , I have updated it with the interceptor code.

Comment: Right. The body is read once and it empty for subsequent calls. As I said: consider to use an `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` instead of default one `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`: see the `request-factory` attribute of that `<int-http:outbound-gateway>`

Comment: My requirement is to log response body that's why I have provided rest-template , but after updating <int-http:outbound-gateway> with request-factory , it throws error like. Configuration problem: When providing a 'rest-template' reference, the 'request-factory' attribute is not allowed.

Comment: That's OK. So, your custom `testSubmitPaymentRestTemplate` has to be supplied with that request factory instead. See its `setRequestFactory(ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory)`

Comment: How to supply ? In Hybris framework, I defined rest template bean as follows: <bean id="testSubmitPaymentRestTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="testRequestLoggingInterceptor"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

Comment: Huh? So just use another `<property name="requestFactory">` and have an `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` as a `<bean>` declared.

Comment: Now I get  this error : Could not properly initialize user sessionorg.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "myURL": Attempted read from closed stream.; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream.

Comment: OK. Let's step back then and try to wrap a response in your interceptor into the `BufferingClientHttpResponseWrapper` before calling your `logResponse()` and return from your `intercept()` method exactly that wrapper already.

Comment: I resolved it by providing , testBufferingClientHttpRequestFactory bean to Rest Template. It is working now. Thanks for your response

Comment: One more question, Is it possible that the status code received in HTTPS response can be available in testSubmitPaymentResponseVO?

Comment: You can do that using an `<enricher>` and copy a value from the `HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE` into your `testSubmitPaymentResponseVO` using its respective setter. See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-transformation.html#payload-enricher

Comment: I am completely new to Spring , I see I am already using a header enricher in XML , My requirement is to make respons estatus code available in my POJO testSubmitPaymentResponseVO. Can you elaborate more on this. That would really be a great help for me

Comment: Your `testSubmitPaymentResponseVO` is a payload of a message after that `<int:json-to-object-transformer>`. It has to have some setter for the status you mention. The `<enricher>` has an option `<int:property name="" expression="" ` where name reflects your setter, kinda Java bean property. The `expression` is just a call for `headers[http_statusCode]`. All the info is available in that doc. Also see samples repo for some ideas: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/