# Can HTTPS response status code made available in other classes in Spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

I have a requirement to make response.statusCode() received from ClientHttpResponse in Interceptor, should be available in testSubmitPaymentResponseVO object that I created so that error handling can be done accordingly . However I dont know where and how to pass response to my POJO testSubmitPaymentResponseVO.

```
<int:channel id="MytestReqRequestChannel"/>

<int:header-enricher input-channel="MytestReqRequestChannel" output-channel="MytestReqEnrichedRequestChannel">
    <int:header name="x-api-key" value="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('myKey')}"/>
    <int:header name="Content-Type" value="application/json;charset=UTF-8" />
</int:header-enricher>


<int:object-to-json-transformer input-channel="MytestReqEnrichedRequestChannel"
                                output-channel="MytestReqJSONRequestChannel"/>

<int-http:outbound-gateway
        url="#{configurationService.configuration.getProperty('myURL')}"
        http-method="POST"
        header-mapper="testPaymentHeaderMapper"
        rest-template="testSubmitPaymentRestTemplate"
        request-channel="MytestReqJSONRequestChannel"
        reply-channel="MytestReqJSONResponseChannel"
        charset="UTF-8"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<int:json-to-object-transformer input-channel="MytestReqJSONResponseChannel"
                                output-channel="MytestReqResponseChannel"
                                type="com.test.testb2bintegrations.models.payment.request.testSubmitPaymentResponseVO"/>

<int:channel id="MytestReqResponseChannel"/>
```

Interceptor code:

```
public class TestRequestLoggingInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor
{

@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException
{
    ClientHttpResponse response;
    try
    {
        request.getHeaders().setAcceptCharset(Collections.singletonList(Charsets.UTF_8));
        long startTimeinMillis = new Date().getTime();
        response = execution.execute(request, body);
        logResponse(response);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LOGGER.error("Error when trying to fetch the information : " + e.getMessage());
        throw new IOException("Connection was unsuccessful!", e);
    }
    return response;
}

private void logResponse(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException
{
       String lineSeparator = System.lineSeparator();
        String responseBody = StreamUtils.copyToString(response.getBody(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder responseLog = new StringBuilder();
        responseLog.append("=======================Response Begin==========================").append(lineSeparator);
        responseLog.append("Status code  : {" + response.getStatusCode() + "}").append(lineSeparator);
        responseLog.append("Status text  : {" + response.getStatusText() + "}").append(lineSeparator);
        responseLog.append("Headers      : {" + response.getHeaders() + "}").append(lineSeparator);
        responseLog.append("Response body: {" + responseBody + "}").append(lineSeparator);
        responseLog.append("======================Response End==============================").append(lineSeparator);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave you some instructions in the comments for my answer for this your question: [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'json' argument must be an instance of: [class java.lang.String, class [B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62720392/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-json-argument-must-be-an-instance-of-cla)

We probably could consider this as a duplication, but that won't hurt me if I repeat myself over here as well.

The HTTP response status code is stored in the respective header when `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` processes the `ClientHttpResponse`:

```
    else {
        replyBuilder = messageBuilderFactory.withPayload(httpResponse);
    }
    replyBuilder.setHeader(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE,
            httpResponse.getStatusCode());
    return replyBuilder.copyHeaders(headers);
```

And this header is simply available downstream for your consideration.

If you really eager to have that status code presented in your `testSubmitPaymentResponseVO`, then you probably need to have a setter on it.

One of the way is to implement some transformer method to accept your `testSubmitPaymentResponseVO` and that header and set it into your POJO and return it from that header:

```
testSubmitPaymentResponseVO setStatusCode(testSubmitPaymentResponseVO pojo, @Header(name = HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE) HttpStatus statusCode) {
   pojo.setStatusCode(statusCode);
   return pojo;
}
```

Another way is to use an `<enricher>` component:

```
<int:enricher id="userEnricher"
              input-channel="setStatusCodeChannel"
              output-channel="MytestReqResponseChannel">
    <int:property name="StatusCode" expression="headers[http_statusCode]"/>
</int:enricher>
```

And your `<int:json-to-object-transformer>` should output to this new `setStatusCodeChannel`.

See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-transformation.html#payload-enricher

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean; if the status code is other than 200, you won't, normally, have a JSON string to convert to your POJO.

You could add an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` to the gateway and handle the exception, and create an appropriate JSON string there. See [adding behavior to endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain),

Comment: Yeah... everything is possible. See my answer: looks like it satisfies the requirements...